# Automated Payment script

Tags: rewards

I am running a baker service with quite some delegators and a really linear staking balance.

quick doubt, how am I supposed to run the auto payment script for this?

Comment: What is "really linear staking balance"? What is "the auto payment script"?

Comment: Just a regular Delegation service with close to 5 to 6 known sources I know have delegated into the baker service. Payouts script can also be automated. I know backerei is of use. But how to get it done? I am quite doubtful. because as of now i am just doing manual payouts.

Comment: The question seems too broad, please make it more specific. The question should be about a specific problem you face, with a reasonably scoped answer. You should research and experiment on your own before asking a question.